# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.10 - Hard Drive not recognized

Tags: installation, 12.10, usb, hard-drive

I have an HP ProBook 4520 and I am trying to do a dual install with Windows 7. The USB device I used only detects itself as an installable location. If I exit the installer and open up the file system, it mounts and detects the 500meg internal drive.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the results of these commands? `mount -l` and `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had a SanDisk card plugged in that I was using with my camera. Removing that media allowed the hard drive to be shown.

Not sure why that had an effect on the installation but taking the SDHC card out worked.